# How to match block of text in vim, ignoring leading whitespaces

Tags: vim

In vim, when visually selected text, we can search for highlighted occurrence with <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

But this match only works within a line. If I have the following code:

```
if condition:
    do_something()
    do_something_else()
    do_something_further()
else:
    if someWeirdCondition:
        // repeated code here
        do_something()
        do_something_else()
        do_something_further()
```

Are there easy way to search the occurrence of the block, which have different white spaces in front?

I could do <kbd>/</kbd>`\\_s*do_something()\\_s*do_something_else()\\_s*do_something_further()`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
do_something()
do_something_else()
do_something_further()
```

Are there easier way?

Comment: If you aren't interested in the `()` then look at `*` to search forward and `#` backwards for the word under the cursor. If you are then `set iskeyword+=(,)` will include them so `#` on `do_something()` will find the previous occurrence

Comment: @Steve I want to match the whole block of code. So can I can know someone is repeating the same logic by copy and pasting code everywhere

Comment: Then a text editor is the wrong tool for the job.  Use a parser, transform the AST to keep only the relevant attributes, and compare the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This mapping, found [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text), can help you to achieve it. Basically, it automatizes your approach to this problem – inserting `\_s` (whitespace or newline character) between the lines.

```
" Search for selected text, forwards or backwards.
vnoremap <silent> * :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy/<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \escape(@", '/\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>
vnoremap <silent> # :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy?<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \escape(@", '?\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>
```

Now your <kbd>*</kbd> is mapped to search forwards for selected text in the `--VISUAL--` mode, and <kbd>#</kbd> to search backwards.